# Python: How to append generator iteration values to a list

Tags: python, list, iteration, generator, permutation

I have a simple generator to give me permutations of a set of coordinates. 
I wish to save each new permutation to an element in an array using the code below:

```
import random
def poss_comb(coord):
    spin=random.shuffle
    if spin:
        spin(coord)
        yield (coord)
...

a=[]
for n in xrange(0,10):
    for item in poss_comb(coord):
        print item
        a.append(item)
```

However when printing the results printing `item` gives me what I want :

```
['0 1', '', '1 2', '1 3']
['0 1', '', '1 2', '1 3']
['1 2', '0 1', '1 3', '']
['0 1', '1 2', '', '1 3']
['1 3', '', '1 2', '0 1']
['1 3', '1 2', '0 1', '']
['0 1', '', '1 3', '1 2']
['1 2', '0 1', '', '1 3']
['1 2', '1 3', '', '0 1']
['', '1 2', '1 3', '0 1']
```

whereas printing `list a` provides an array where each element is a copy of the last permutation.

What would be a better way to do this?

Comment: Does your function yield the global `coord` or the local `link`?

Comment: They are the same, I changed link to coord when posting for simplicity. (corrected now)

Comment: What exactly is a `coord`? It's not defined anywhere.

Comment: You're simple generator `poss_comb()` only yields one value.

Comment: It's worth noting that there's a much easier way to append each yielded value from a generator to a list: `a = list(poss_comb(coord))` (or `a.extend(poss_comb(coord))` if you want to append them to an existing list instead of a new one).

Comment: Also, there's usually no good reason to write a generator that only generates one value—and, when there is, it usually makes more sense to just call `next()` on it instead of making a list out of its one value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your generator does not yield *new* lists, it yields the *same list* over and over again. When you append that yielded reference to `a` you only get to see the same original list, in it's most recently shuffled form, over and over again.

Yield a copy instead:

```
def poss_comb(coord):
    coord = coord[:]  # use a local copy of the list
    random.shuffle(coord)
    yield coord
```

or create a random sort instead of using inplace shuffling with the `sorted()` function:

```
def poss_comb(coord):
    yield sorted(coord, key=lambda k: random.random())
```

Comment: There's no reason to create a `lambda` that just calls a function; just pass the function itself. (Edited the answer to fix it.)

Comment: @abarnert: that would only work if `random.random` took an argument.  I think you need to revert.

Comment: @DSM: The original version created a lambda with no arguments, so this works in exactly the same cases as the original… but if neither one worked, we need a new edit…

Comment: Actually… I don't think this is a good idea in the first place. Using an unstable key with a stable sort like timsort means unbounded worst-case time! And even if that weren't a problem, it would still be O(N log N) instead of O(N). like `shuffle`. If this is an optimization to avoid the cost of copying the list, it's a pessimization. If you want a non-in-place `shuffled` function that doesn't require pre-copying, the right way to do it is to insert each elements in random order. But pre-copying is going to be simpler, and probably faster too.

Comment: @abarnert: ah, you're right, the original suffers the same flaw.  I haven't thought about the unstable key aspect, but I thought it was specified that the key function would only ever be evaluated once for each element, in which case from sort's perspective there *is* no instability.  (Thinking through algorithm orders hurts my brain, so I'll defer on worst-case behaviour considerations.)

Comment: @DSM: Is it actually specified or guaranteed anywhere that the key is only called once per element? I looked for it in `sorted` and `list.sort`, and in the writeup on how timsort works, and none of them say that. Of course CPython 2.4-3.3 _do_ only call key once, but without a specification saying which tradeoff is required, do you want to trust which one an implementation chooses (especially given that using `cmp` doesn't cache results)?

Comment: @abarnert: this is one of those things which could just be folk wisdom.  The official sorting [howto](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/sorting.html#key-functions) (which has Hettinger as a co-author) says "The value of the key parameter should be a function that takes a single argument and returns a key to use for sorting purposes. This technique is fast because the key function is called exactly once for each input record.", which is evidence, though not conclusive.

Comment: @DSM: I suppose you can guarantee the CPython 2.4-3.4 behavior by explicitly DSUing the same way it does implicitly: `[y[1] for y in sorted((key(x), x) for x in foo)]`. But that's obviously going to be slower (by a constant factor, but maybe a big one). And besides, CPython also implements `sorted` by just copying and calling `sort`, so really, you might as well just do copy-and-shuffle in the first place if you're relying on CPython details…

Comment: @abarnert: I did forget the lambda argument and I dud rely on the key being called only once. And of course `sorted()` *has* to copy the original sequence in full to create a sorted copy. But I like the one-liner here, it does the job.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: `sorted` doesn't have to pre-copy the sequence; it could merge/insert into an empty sequence, instead of pre-copying and re-merging in-place. And your code kind of implies to the reader that he should expect it do to that (and that there's a benefit to it). Anyway, turning this into a one-liner to evade the expression/statement distinction makes things more confusing—it's obvious what `shuffle` does, but less obvious what this does. You could wrap it in a function called `shuffled`… but then why not use the obvious implementation in `shuffled`?

Comment: @abarnert: Sorry, I didn't mean to imply the copy couldn't be done during sorting; I meant that `sorted()` is documented to return a new list, the input sequence isn't affected. I gave both options to the OP, both of which create a shuffled copy of the input list, I don't *think* my answer implies that using `sorted()` is more efficient than creating an explicit copy and using `shuffle()` on that. It'd be interesting to compare the two approaches.